# Moving an image with Javascript onclick?

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage that contains an image and some links. Each of the links execute different functions when clicked.

When a certain link is clicked, I call a function called `move`. When this link is clicked, I need the image (`bird`) to move 20px to the right.

So far, my function looks like this:

```
function move(e) {
   bird.style.position = "relative";
   bird.style.left += "20px";
   e.preventDefault();     //prevents the page from redirecting
}
```

This works, but only one time. When I click the link, `bird` will move 20px to the right, but this will only happen once. I need the photo to move 20 more px EVERY time the link is clicked. A friend told me to "parse it before adding it" but I'm not really sure what they mean. What should I be parsing? Any suggestions/help are very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: jQuery animate function can help you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here we go:

HTML:

```
<div id="block"></div>
<button id="go">&raquo; Run</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#go").click(function(){
  var dest = parseInt($("#block").css("margin-left").replace("px", "")) + 100;
    if (dest > 500) {
        $("#block").animate({
            marginLeft: "10px"
          }, 500 );
    }
    else {
      $("#block").animate({
        marginLeft: dest + "px"
      }, 500 );
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
div { width: 20px; height: 20px; background: green; margin: 10px; }
```

Hope it helps;)

http://jsfiddle.net/schadeck/ptGws/

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event listener to your link and then use the `tranform: translateX(20px)` CSS rule to move the element. The `translateX` will move the element from where it is currently on the page.

```js
var bird = document.getElementById("img");
var link = document.getElementById("link");
link.addEventListener("click", move);

var birdX = 0;
function move(e) {
   birdX += 20;
   bird.style.position = "relative";
   bird.style.transform = "translateX(" + birdX + "px)";
   e.preventDefault();     //prevents the page from redirecting
}
```

```css
div{ /*just for effect*/ 
  border:1px solid brown; 
  display:inline-block;
}
a{
  cursor:pointer;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="img">bird</div>
<br>
<a id="link">Link</a>
```

Comment: `style="position: relative; transform: translateX(20px) translateX(20px) translateX(20px) translateX(20px) translateX(20px);"` Yeeesh...

Comment: @Amleonard, little better now!

Comment: Very nice very nice!

Answer (score 1):

```
function move(e) {
   var left = parseInt(bird.style.left);

   bird.style.position = "relative";
   bird.style.left = (left+20)+"px";
   e.preventDefault();     //prevents the page from redirecting
}
```

This is the closest to your original code but I don't like it that much. I'd more prefer something like:

```
var offsetLeft = 0;

function move(e) {
   offsetLeft += 20;

   bird.style.position = "relative";
   bird.style.left = (offsetLeft)+"px";
   e.preventDefault();     //prevents the page from redirecting
}
```

But that does create an extra variable, what a world!

Answer (score 0):

`bird.style.left += "20px"` will only work once because you're building a string — with the next click, the `left` property will be `20px20px`, and that's not valid CSS.

What your friend may mean by parsing is "convert the position value to an integer, add 20, and then set the `left` property to that instead of appending it". That's what praguan's answer does, it looks like — it'll work, but it may not be what you're looking for if you're not using jQuery. (Not everyone is.)

I think we could do without the parsing, and instead use a separate variable to keep track of the position:

```
<img id="bird" src="http://placehold.it/150" />
<br />
<a id="move-link" href="#">move the image</a>
```

```
var bird = document.getElementById('bird');
var moveLink = document.getElementById('move-link');
var position = 0;

bird.style.position = 'relative';

moveLink.onclick = function() {
  position += 20;
  bird.style.left = position + 'px';
}
```

[Here's a JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qbt1wsqm/) showing how it could be done.